# My SSH keys no longer work

Tags: 22.04, ssh, login, sshd

For some reason my VPS ignores/bypasses the passphrase for my pubic/private SSH keys and logs me in automatically, without the need for a passphrase or password.

I haven't made any changes or even updated anything, so I have no idea where to begin.

I have two VPS servers running Ubuntu 22.04. The one with the issue at login says: `Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-id" from agent.` The other one that needs a passphrase is: `Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-id" Passphrase for key "rsa-key-id"` So it's the one with `From Agent` that logs in automatically.

I haven't done anything obvious to set that up. It always needed the passphrase until recently. Can I remove that and change it back to needing a passphrase?

Comment: Are you using an ssh authentication agent on the client system?

Comment: Tell us a bit more about the two computers, the local and the remote. Which OS are they running? An ssh authentication agent can store the passphrase for you and apply it automatically.

Comment: Thank you @user68186 I just discovered (I have 2 VPS servers running Ubuntu 22.04). One, (the one with the issue says: Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-id" from agent.

The one that needs a passphrase is: Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-id" Passphrase for key "rsa-key-id" So, its the one with "Freom Agent" that logs in automatically. I havent done anything obvious to set that up. It always needed the passphrase until recently. Can I remove that and change it back to Passphrase.

Comment: @Hawk007 you still haven't told us what **client** system you are connecting to these VPSes from - is it Ubuntu 22.04 also? if so, is it the default gnome desktop or something else? That is where you need to look for the ssh-agent configuration.

Comment: @steeldriver its Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-89-generic x86_64) Server. I am using Putty to connect. But also WinSCP. My PC is windows 10 where Putty is installed?

Comment: *on Windows*, both putty and WinSCP can be configured on a per-connection basis to use `pagent` - I wasn't aware that WinSCP was available for Ubuntu, so I'll let someone else take it from here

Comment: @steeldriver thanks anyway. This has to be something server side as both putty and WinSPC login automatically where before they required the passphrase. Something changed on the server?

Comment: No, the change should be on the client side putty, WinSCP. The passphrase is stored with the private key, which is stored in the client. First check the settings of putty and WinSCP. Windows may have updated these, and defaults may have changed. Second use the command `ssh -vvvv username@<host name or IP address>` from your computer that has putty and WinSCP. Then copy and paste the output directly in your question above. Finally format pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question window.

Comment: since your ssh/scp **client** is running on Windows, you likely **do** have `pagent` running and have configured **one** of the connections to use it. See [How to tell if PuTTY is using my ssh key from Pageant or not](https://superuser.com/questions/879159/how-to-tell-if-putty-is-using-my-ssh-key-from-pageant-or-not) and [Using Pageant for authentication](https://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant)

Comment: Thanks @user68186 - I have never used Pagent, and have never noticed it before just now, after you mentioned it. There is one key in it (View Keys). Can I just mremove the key from Pagent and then it will require a Passphrase? Thanks again. I'll look deeper into this in the morening.

Comment: Thanks and @steeldriver I closed Pagent and it now requires the Passphrase. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: I closed Pagent and it now requires the Passphrase. Thanks again. Much appreciated. Thanks @user68186